# need to prepare for $5$ out of $6$ outcomes

Tags: combinatorics

Four of six possible essay questions will be on the exam. If two questions are in part $A$ and two questions are in part $B$, and one question must be chosen from both part $A$ and $B$, how many essay questions must be studied for? I think it's $5$ but am not sure.

TBH honest the original directions were ambiguous but I think part A will have the same number as questions in it as part B, and one question must be chosen from part A and one question must be chosen from part B.

For completeness sake here is the original

> Four of  the questions  from  below  will  be  on  the  exam,  divided
>   into  Part  A  and  Part  B.  You  will  have  to  answer  one 
>   question  from  part  A,  and  one question  from

Comment: Are there $3$ questions in each part?

Comment: As I understand it, for the exam you must pick one question from $A$ and one from $B$ and answer them, is that right? If so, you might want to clarify that.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, that's right.

Assuming that the exam has two parts, A and B, both consisting of two essay questions, chosen from a collection of 6 possible questions, of which you must pick and answer one for each part, you will have to study for 5 of them. If you study for less, there is a chance that you haven't studied for *both* questions in at least one of the parts.

The number of parts to the exam doesn't matter, what matters is the smallest number of questions to a part, $k$ and the total number of questions, $n$. You will have to study for $n-k+1$ questions, otherwise there is a possibility that the part will feature exactly the $k$ questions you didn't study for.

Comment: True, assuming that:

1) The parts $A$ and $B$ are predetermined and known and
2) The questions are selected by the student

Comment: Would the downvoters care to explain themselves? The answer is correct and explained.